# iphone - JavaScriptCore Framework / library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, frameworks, ios-frameworks

Has any one used JavaScriptCore framework/library in iOS project?
I do not see any such framework available in the existing framework list so I downloaded the source code from Apple Open Source site http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/ios-40/

Now I want to know what I need to do to integrate this in my application. Are these API already present in SDK  and I can just call the methods by copying just headers or I need to copy all the source code in to the project?

I have a working project which just copy and import headers. But I am not able to understand how it works. It has a method as below which is called at the startup.

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
@implementation JSCocoaSymbolFetcher
+ (void)populateJavascriptCoreSymbols
{
_JSEvaluateScript = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "JSEvaluateScript");
_JSGarbageCollect = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "JSGarbageCollect");
_JSGlobalContextCreate = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "JSGlobalContextCreate");
_JSGlobalContextRetain = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "JSGlobalContextRetain");
_JSGlobalContextRelease = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "JSGlobalContextRelease");
_JSContextGetGlobalObject = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "JSContextGetGlobalObject");
_JSClassCreate = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "JSClassCreate");
_JSClassRetain = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "JSClassRetain");
.
.
.//other similar code
.
}
```

It also has methods like this before the @implementation

```
JSValueRef (*_JSEvaluateScript)(JSContextRef ctx, JSStringRef script, JSObjectRef thisObject, JSStringRef sourceURL, int startingLineNumber, JSValueRef* exception);
JSValueRef JSEvaluateScript(JSContextRef ctx, JSStringRef script, JSObjectRef thisObject, JSStringRef sourceURL, int startingLineNumber, JSValueRef* exception)
{
return _JSEvaluateScript(ctx, script, thisObject, sourceURL, startingLineNumber, exception);
}

void (*_JSGarbageCollect)(JSContextRef ctx);
void JSGarbageCollect(JSContextRef ctx)
{
return _JSGarbageCollect(ctx);
}
```

So My question is

1) Any one has tried using JavaScriptCore for iPhone application? if yes How?

2) what dlsym method does?

3) how the methods mentioned at the last works? e.g. `void (*_JSGarbageCollect)(JSContextRef ctx);
    void JSGarbageCollect(JSContextRef ctx)
    {
    return _JSGarbageCollect(ctx);
    }`

Comment: I believe you are not allowed to use JavaScriptCore directly in an iOS app.  The only allowed way to execute JS is a UIWebView.  Which is pretty damn lame if you ask me.

Comment: But why Apple will provide source code http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/ios-40/ If we cant use it in iOS app?

Comment: @Squeegy that's no longer true, they allow you to run interpreters in your app as long as it does not download code after it has been reviewed for the app store.

Answer (score 0):

You can bundle JavaScriptCore with your app, but you have to include the entire project in your application. See http://www.phoboslab.org/log/2011/04/ios-and-javascript-for-real-this-time for more details.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't really give good information as to how the apple-provided code should be structured into an xcode project for iOS to run, plus you have to pay for the jscore they altered.